ADB install on physical device is not working
I recently purchased a macbook air M3.
After configuring basic android developer setup. 
I am running into a problem where I am not able to install any .APK file using adb install.
I believe android studio internally also uses ADB CLI to 'run and launch' any application which is also not working for me.
When I do 'adb devices' on terminal. My physical device is listed.
The same applications, I am able to install and run on an emulator either by terminal or using android studio directly.
I have two physical/real devices and I have tested on both of them. The is persists on both.
When I try adb shell input text on any application, it works.
I have an older M1 Macbook pro in which I am able to run and launch any application which rules out that the cable is faulty.
When I used wireless debugging option. I am able to run and launch the application.
The things that I have already tried to resolve the issue.

Turning off and on the USB debugging option from developer tools in phone setting.
Restart my laptop, restart my phones, restart ADB.
Reinstall ADB.
Reinstall and update android studio.
Reinstall SDK and SDK related platform-tools.

Android studio version -- Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 2
Any insight on how to resolve this weird problem?
Update 1:
I reset my OSX and installed everything again. I am still facing the issue.
Update 2:
OS version is Sonoma 14.3

Does it show any error?

No, it just timeout after 5 minutes ( I think that is the default timeout )

only install hangs? what about adb shell?

I tried 'adb shell input text' it worked fine every time.

Have you tried a different USB cable? adb shell input text only transmits a few hundred bytes, that is not comparable to an APK with multiple MB of size. A defect cable could interrupt the installation. As the problem seems to be on USB level the OS is important. Unfortunately you forgot to mention your MacOS version. Please edit your question and add the macOS version.

Please consider that the M1 and M3 feature different USB port specs and therefore might require USB cables with different specs. Even the M1 already has USB 3.1 and USB 4.0. On the other hand, the M3 only has USB 4.0. Find a cable certified for "40Gbps USB4.0"; the phone also has to support that. Raising the timeout to make it work with a bad cable can't be the answer, when the cable is supposed to make 40Gbps. The maximum length is 80cm.

Hi @Robert, I have updated the OS version.
I have only one usb 3.0 cable which I have tried with and it is not working. Other cables which I have never worked with my M1 ( I did try with those cables too and still it did not work )

Hi @MartinZeitler, I do not have a USB 4.0 supporting setup. I will try to get a cable and a device. If this turns out to be a solution. I will consider moving away from MBP/MBA towards Ubuntu :-)

@ArunMehra  When you can send small files and large file will time-out, I'd assume that the transfer has packet loss, which may well come from a cable not sufficiently shielded. If case you can find a cable that is "known to be working", please leave an answer (one can vote to reopen).

Hi @MartinZeitler, changing the cable did work. Even though the cable I used is still not USB 4.0 but it works. I apologise for the late reply.

When the device does not have an USB 4.0 port, this will always be a downgraded connection.. The cable's shielding is a crucial aspect, with such high-speed connections, in general.
